# Migrating answers from (new) users which should be questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, migration, new-users

It seems quite frequent that a new user will ask their question as an answer to an existing question. Presumably they find that existing one via google and ask in the answer box without really understanding the site.

What tends to happen is they get told to ask as a new question, often it’s friendly and sometimes it’s not particularly. Generally though, it doesn’t get asked as a new question and the ‘answer’ ends up getting deleted.

I assume the new users just think “sod it” and go somewhere else. This can’t be good for the retention of new users or their view of the site.

What if there was the means to have the answer migrated to a new question all of its own, with a link to the existing question for context? I realise it’s asking for a lot, but should we be asking SE for a feature like this? I think it would be far more constructive and welcoming.

Comment: Sounds like that would be a good feature. You should suggest it on global meta, if it's not already been suggested.

Answer (score 6):

As David Richerby alludes to, we don't have the ability to implement new features that deviate from the larger Stack Exchange community. The place to raise these issues to the SE overlords is [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

As it happens, someone has [already made this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/convert-non-answers-into-new-questions). Unfortunately, it seems that the majority of the community doesn't want this feature at the moment. Please join the discussion there in order to get this feature implemented.